# JUnits for constructors which uses third party API call

Tags: java, junit4, powermock, easymock

Below mentioned is the class that I need to test:

```
public class MyClass {
     private String key;
     public MyClass(Connection con) {
         key = ThirdPartyApi.getkey(con);
     }
     public String getKey() {
         return key;
     }
}
```

Now I need to test this constructor, but am unable to mock this Third party API call. And the Test case would be as mentioned below :

```
public class MyClassTest{
 @Test
 public void test1(){
     MyClass c = new MyClass(dummyconnection);
     assertNotNull(c.getKey != null);
 }
}
```

But this case would be giving me an error that ThirdPartyAPI Class is failing as the the connection object is mocked.

So I want to mock this ThirdPartyApi call. Is it possible using Easymock, powermock?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the key as argument?

Comment: I think my question was a bit unclear, I have edited it again.

Comment: I say the same: why not passing the key directly to the constructor???

Comment: As you explained, what you want to do is test your `getKey()` function ?

Comment: This is the scenario that i want to test "If I call the constructor and mock the Thirdparty API call, is my key value properly set with the value returned from the mocked  Thirdparty API call" as expect(ThirdPartyMockAPI.getKey).andReturn(testKey);

Comment: Testing a one-line method achieves nothing.  Spend your time somewhere else.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem There are many more lines in the constructor, but this line is the one blocking me. For some reasons I can post the entire code here. So if you have some good suggestions please suggest

Comment: Well, to answer your question exactly, you're trying to stub a static method.  Easymock doesn't do that out of the box, which is why you need to use PowerMock with it - and it's exactly the same as stubbing any other static method, which is well explained in the PowerMock documentation.  However, whether you should actually be doing this is a different story.  A constructor should be a very simple piece of code, without that much logic in it.  If it were me, I'd be thinking how to design my class differently.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: EasyMock does not support mocking **static** calls. So you can turn to PowerMock(ito) or JMockit in case you do not want to change *your* code.

But the *better* approach would be to understand that using *static* always leads to tight coupling between your classes, and that you want to make sure that this doesn't affect your ability to unit test your code.

In your case:

```
public MyClass(Connection con) {
  key = ThirdPartyApi.getkey(con);
```

simply replace that with:

```
public MyClass(Connection con) {
  this (ThirdPartyApi.getkey(con));
}

/** unit testing only */
MyClass(Key key) {
  ...
```

And voila, you got a constructor that you can call from your unit test - and now you simply pass a *mocked* key object. And your tests will no longer execute that static call - because you use the key-taking constructor in all your tests.

But you probably want another test case to make sure that calling the *public* constructor does what you expect it to do - and that could be to throw an exception because that static call fails.

Beyond that: I fully agree with the comments - the fact that your constructor is doing so much (including static calls) has a certain design smell on it.